# What does the term 'photorealistic' really mean?

Tags: graphics, rendering, shaders, terminology

I was wondering about the term 'photorealistic' in regards to rendering and was wondering how this is used.

Is it used to describe a shader (or set of) that have certain quantifiable features? Or any rendering thats not meant to be abstract, like the cartoon effect seen in Borderlands? Or is it just a subjective term meaning 'really really realistic'?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just really really realistic.

Comment: When looking at a rendering and thinking it's a photograph. The last one I've seen was a scene in 3dsmax, render time: 60 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone, whenever i've seen the term used its usually fit well with subjective use but looking around at various 'photorealistic' examples I just wanted to see if there was anything more to it. Im not really sure how to pick answers for questions like this so I selected Roger Perkins as that was the first in, but up votes all round as all are very helpful :) Thanks

Comment: (My account from SO has not 'migrated' so I may not upvote yet but I will as soon as I get required rep here)

Comment: @Dave, do you know where I can view that render?

Comment: @sebf It was a couple of years ago, I believe rendered with 3dsmax6 showing kind of a living room. Try to search the archives at 3dtotal.com (Scene gallery images).

Comment: @Dave, thanks, I find those renders amazing; I also wonder how long a 60 hr render in Max 6 would take to do nowdays in Max 2011?

Comment: The really long hour renders could be from unbiased renderers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've worked on a few games that have been described as photorealistic and I'd have to say it's purely subjective, especially as what we might describe as photorealistic today won't in a few years (as hardware improves, rendering gets closed to perfection and people's expectations of games goes up).

You can apply the term to anything that is rendered, I would take it to mean that what your describing looks as real as you can make it (be that the shading, textures, lighting, etc). In an ideal world, a screenshot would look just like a photo taken on a camera.

Answer (score 10):

When I've seen the term "photorealistic" used, it's shorthand for "trying to be photorealistic."  That is, aiming for the rendered picture to look as real as possible, and using as much real physics with regard to lighting that the machine can handle.

Most rendering is photorealistic, or trying to be.  If you make a conscious choice toward the stylized, as in Borderlands, you're no longer photorealistic.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say.